# MVVM Too many properties

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm making a WPF project and trying to stick to the MVVM pattern. It has close to 20 `UserControl`s, each with about 10 controls I want to be able to change the properties of. For each one, I need to be able to change `Visibility` and `IsEnabled` (Framework element properties), and then change the content/text as well. That is at least 3 properties per control. Across all `UserControl`s, that makes for 600 properties...

I toyed with the idea of making a `ControlProperties` class, and having each control bind to the proper instance's member variable/property. (For example)

```
//Code-behind
public class ControlProperties
{
    private bool m_isEnabled;
    public property IsEnabled
    {
        get { return m_isEnabled; }
        set { m_isEnabled = value; notifyPropertyChanged("IsEnabled"); }
    }

    ControlProperties() { m_isEnabled = false; }
}

public ControlProperties controlOne;


//XAML
<Button IsEnabled={Binding controlOne.IsEnabled}/>
```

Is there a way to combine the 2+ properties of each control into something more reusable/easier to implement, other than using the above class? (Each Control needs it's own "instance", they aren't sharing the same values) One downside of the above way is that each control has to individually bind the wanted properties. I would have to in the first place...but still.

Please ask questions if I left anything out or was unclear about something.

Comment: From you XAML example is your datacontext The controlProperties?
If so, at first glance i would advise against it

Comment: The `UserControl` that the `Button` is in sets its `DataContext` to my ViewModel.

Comment: Don't know exactly what you mean by Controls. I never used CustomControls, only Controls; Never had the need to cross that barrier

Comment: if you do not have a specific XAML control to bind these two properties i would explicit bind everything
If the two to-be-bound properties can be encapsulated in a 'common' control then that control would specify its own datacontext - i believe you're already doing so

Comment: By Controls, I mean things inheriting from `UIControl`, anything from `Button`s to `TextBlock`s. And ya, as far as I'm aware, this method should work (trying to iron out the bugs on my end right now), but I'm wondering if there are better ways to do it. Be it changing how my class works, or changing how it is done altogether.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to combine the 2+ properties of each control into something more reusable/easier to implement, other than using the above class?

I am not sure that I understand exactly what you are after here but you may want to consider using one or several attached dependency properties: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011(v=vs.110).aspx

Such a property can be defined in a stand-alone class:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class SharedProperties
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsEnabledProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "IsEnabled",
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(SharedProperties),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false));

        public static void SetIsEnabled(UIElement element, bool value)
        {
            element.SetValue(IsEnabledProperty, value);
        }
        public static bool GetIsEnabled(UIElement element)
        {
            return (bool)element.GetValue(IsEnabledProperty);
        }
    }
}
```

...and then be set on any UIElement:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Window21" Height="300" Width="300">
    <StackPanel>
        <UserControl local:SharedProperties.IsEnabled="True" />

        <Button x:Name="btn" local:SharedProperties.IsEnabled="{Binding SomeSourceProperty}" />
    ...
```

---

```
//get:
bool isEnabled = SharedProperties.GetIsEnabled(btn);
//set:
SharedProperties.SetIsEnabled(btn, true);
```

Comment: Each control needs its own "instance" of whatever is used. I'm not sharing the same value across all of them. I updated my question accordingly

Comment: I guess you didn't read the link. Values of dependency properties are *not* shared across controls. Each control gets its own value but the property itself is only defined once and in one place. Please refer to the link I supplied for more information.